# Does SQL Server retain UPDLOCK for subqueries?

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to determine more efficient ways to perform some database operations.

One of the issues that we have is with an ancient primary key system where the primary key for a new record is selected by finding the `MAX` value in the table and then adding 1 (we cannot change this implementation, please don't suggest this as an answer).

There are some different approaches that we can take to resolve this issue (table-valued parameters, temp tables, etc), but we can never assume that another process won't insert another record during this process and business rules will not allow us to lock the table.

So, the crux of my question is, if we get the current `MAX` value in a sub-query using an `UPDLOCK` hint, will the lock hint last for the life of the containing query?

For example:

```
INSERT 
  INTO table1 
     ( PKColumn, 
       DataColumn1, 
       DataColumn2 )
VALUES SELECT MAX(ISNULL(PKColumn, 0) + 1) FROM table1 WITH (UPDLOCK)) + RowNumber ,
       DataColumn1 ,
       DataColumn2 
  FROM @Table1Temp
```

If we use this to insert 100,000 records, for example, will the `UPDLOCK` hint hold on the table until all records are inserted or is it released as soon as the initial value is retrieved?

Comment: "we cannot change this implementation, please don't suggest this as an answer" -  This problem is always going to cause you grief. Fix the real problem, not the symptoms!

Comment: @MitchWheat: that's nice to say from an outside standpoint, but the core application is 20 years old, written in VB6 with a very near-term EOL. It is financially unviable to make a change of this magnitude at this stage of the product's life. Therefore we are looking for other approaches to solving performance problems for our numerous existing customer until its replacement is completed.

Comment: "with a very near-term EOL." - then do nothing.

Comment: @MitchWheat: also not financially viable due to the millions in annual support revenue. Although the product may be nearing EOL, the projects that are managed in the application may span multiple years and transitioning to a new platform is not viable. All we are trying to do is help our customers out with their current problems.

Comment: where do I get some of these "...millions in annual support revenue" ? :)

Comment: @MitchWheat: write a great product that thrives for 20 years...

Comment: I've done that.......But describing the product you mention above as great with that mechanism might be stretching it a bit! ;)

Comment: @MitchWheat: that's some very helpful commentary. Appreciate the assistance in assessing our products (running in SAAS, self-host, with web, desktop, and mobile implementations) and customer acceptance (over 100,000 active users).

Comment: You're welcome. No charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifies that update locks are to be taken and held until the
>   transaction completes. UPDLOCK takes update locks for read operations
>   only at the row-level or page-level. If UPDLOCK is combined with
>   TABLOCK, or a table-level lock is taken for some other reason, an
>   exclusive (X) lock will be taken instead.

So yes. The transaction will last at least as long as that statement. (Possibly longer if you aren't using auto commit transactions and have multiple statements in a transaction)

Comment: does that guarantee that multiple clients won't result in deadlock performing MAX(col) + 1? "UPDLOCK takes update locks for read operations only at the row-level or page-level" - what happens if it escalates to  a page lock?

Comment: @MitchWheat it shouldn't result in deadlock except if both transactions have already taken out and are retaining `S` locks on that row for some reason. And assuming `col` is indexed probably unlikely to end up with page locks but something for the OP to test. The problem with it is that it serialises inserts but this is unavoidable.

Comment: ...without changing the table structure.